# On numerical integration of $\int x\rho(x) dx$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, numerical-methods

Let $\rho:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R_+$ be a density function. For each $n\ge 1$ and $q=(q_1,\ldots, q_d)\in\mathbb Z^d$, define the box $V_q^n$ by

$$V_q^n \quad :=\quad \left\{x=(x_1,\ldots, x_d)\in\mathbb R^d:\quad \frac{q_i}{n} \le x_i < \frac{q_i+1}{n},~ \mbox{for } i=1,\ldots, d \right\}.$$

Set

$$I ~:=~ \int_{\mathbb R^d} |x|\rho(x)dx \quad \mbox{and} \quad I_n~ :=~ \sum_{q\in\mathbb Z^d} \int_{V_q^n} \frac{|q|}{n}\rho\left(\frac{q}{n}\right)dx ~ = ~ \sum_{q\in\mathbb Z^d} \frac{|q|}{n^{d+1}}\rho\left(\frac{q}{n}\right).$$

I am interested in the quantity $|I-I_n|$. It seems to be an elementary question, however I am unable to find related references (even under suitable conditions). Any comments or references will be very much appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you're discretizing the integral using the values on an infinite grid of little boxes of size $1/n$? I believe the difference $|I - I_n|$ can be bounded by an expression involving the gradient of $|x| \rho(x)$.

Comment: @JohnBarber Thanks kindly for the reply. Indeed, this seems to be a fundamental problem. But I'm not familiar with numerical methods. Do you know any related reference?

Comment: When you say "numerical methods", do you mean a numerical method to evaluate $I$, $I_n$, $|I - I_n|$, or all three? Assuming you have an analytic form for $\rho(x)$, your expression for $I_n$ *is* a numerical method for evaluating $I$ if you plug the sum into a program such as Mathematica. One possibility for getting an idea of the behavior of $|I - I_n|$ is to approximate $I$ using a much higher value for $n$ (fine mesh) and comparing it to $I_n$ for a lower value of $n$. Another is to use Monte Carlo techniques to evaluate $I$. Can you generate samples from the pdf $\rho(x)$?